# exphbs is not a function in express-handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am learning by watching tutorials. I don't know what type of error is and how to solve this error.
terminal give me this error
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
^

[image: TypeError: exphbs is not a function]

```
const express = require('express');

const path = require('path')
const port = 3000;
const app = express();


var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');


app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));
app.use('/', require(path.join(__dirname, 'routes/blog.js')))
```

TypeError: exphbs is not a function

```
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`blog app running at http://localhost:${port} `);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) for the module you are using.

> ```
> import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';
> ...
> app.engine('handlebars', engine());
> ```

It uses ES6 syntax but shows that the engine is available from the `engine` property of the module and **not** the top level export.

In your syntax, that would be:

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs.engine());
```